# Why is LOAD DATA from text file into table not working properly in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-5.7

I have a table `event` as:

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name   | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date   | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type   | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| remark | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now I wish to insert some data into this table from a text file `event.txt`. The text file is as:

```
Tommy   2000-01-02  litter  4 kittens, 3 females, 1 male
Bowser  2001-04-26  vet needed break straightened
puffball    2002-05-13  birthday    gave him a new chew toy
```

The whitespaces after values are tabs. The last values are sentences with actual whitespaces. When I load this txt file into the table `event`it doesn't load the values properly. I run the query:

```
load data local infile 'D:/Softwear/mysql/install/data/event.txt' into table event;
```

The table generated is as following:

```
+----------+------------+----------+-------------------------------+
| name     | date       | type     | remark                        |
+----------+------------+----------+-------------------------------+
 |Tommy    | 2000-01-02 | litter   | 4 kittens, 3 females, 1 male
    |ser   | 2001-04-26 | vet      | needed break straightened
| puffball | 2002-05-13 | birthday | gave him a new chew toy       |
+----------+------------+----------+-------------------------------+
```

The value `bowser` is truncated. Why is it so? When I uploaded a similar `pet.txt` file into table `pet` then the table generated correctly. I used notepad to write the txt file, used `tab` after values and `newline` after rows.

Comment: No hidden char in your file ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus What is hidden character? I don't know anything about this. I just typed manually all the characters in notepad.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Now I tried putting a `tab` before each `newline` and the data is loaded well. But the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loading-tables.html) doesn't mention that. And moreover my previous table uploaded well with no `tab` before the `newlines`.